# If...elseif not working for more than 2 conditions?

Tags: php, html, forms, if-statement

I have created a form in html with multiple buttons named differently as (sub1,2,3..so on) but put same value to all of them (value="Update"). I was having a problem that when any of the button was clicked it could control all of my input boxes so I searched for a solution to this problem and came across a php script of if..elseif statements but when I tried to run it, only first two if and elseif conditions were compiled and rest of the conditions were ignored.
Below is my php code, so please guys help me to figure out this problem. I'm sure my question would help many others too :)

```
<?php 
if($_POST['header']){
    if(isset($_POST['header']) && trim($_POST['header']) != ""){
$fp = fopen("assets/config_header.php", 'w');
fwrite($fp, '<?php');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '$header = "'.trim($_POST['header']).'";');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '?>');
fclose($fp); 
}
}
elseif($_POST['color']) {
    if(isset($_POST['color']) && trim($_POST['color']) != ""){
$fp = fopen("assets/config_header5.php", 'w');
fwrite($fp, '<?php');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '$color= "'.trim($_POST['color']).'";');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '?>');
fclose($fp);

}
}
elseif($_POST['headline']) {
if(isset($_POST['headline']) && trim($_POST['headline']) != ""){
$fp = fopen("assets/config_header1.php", 'w');
fwrite($fp, '<?php');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '$headline = "'.trim($_POST['headline']).'";');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '?>');
fclose($fp); 
}
}
elseif($_POST['color1']) {
if(isset($_POST['color1']) && trim($_POST['color1']) != ""){
$fp = fopen("assets/config_header6.php", 'w');
fwrite($fp, '<?php');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '$color1= "'.trim($_POST['color1']).'";');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '?>');
fclose($fp);
}
}
elseif($_POST['subhead']) {
if(isset($_POST['subhead']) && trim($_POST['subhead']) != ""){
$fp = fopen("assets/config_header2.php", 'w');
fwrite($fp, '<?php');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '$subhead = "'.trim($_POST['subhead']).'";');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '?>');
fclose($fp); 
}
}
elseif($_POST['color2']) {
if(isset($_POST['color2']) && trim($_POST['color2']) != ""){
$fp = fopen("assets/config_header7.php", 'w');
fwrite($fp, '<?php');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '$color2= "'.trim($_POST['color2']).'";');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '?>');
fclose($fp);

}
}
elseif($_POST['prodname']) {
if(isset($_POST['prodname']) && trim($_POST['prodname']) != ""){
$fp = fopen("assets/config_header3.php", 'w');
fwrite($fp, '<?php');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '$prodname= "'.trim($_POST['prodname']).'";');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '?>');
fclose($fp);

}
}
elseif($_POST['vidid']) {
if(isset($_POST['vidid']) && trim($_POST['vidid']) != ""){
$fp = fopen("assets/config_header4.php", 'w');
fwrite($fp, '<?php');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '$vidid= "'.trim($_POST['vidid']).'";');
fwrite($fp, ' ');
fwrite($fp, '?>');
fclose($fp);

}

}

?>
```

Thanks in advance :) and yeah if there is any shorter way to execute this task then please do let me know :)

Comment: you dont need the `else if` when you closed the `if` before

Comment: do you want to check the condition inside second if condition ??

Comment: @Drudge No I don't want it to be nested but to be in an else if ladder

Comment: @JoshStevens Sir, can you please elaborate or can you please write correct code at least upto 4 conditions? It would really help me a lot to understand much better as I'm new to php language i have worked in c++ and java before this.

Comment: If all the post variables reside in one html form, you don't have to check with `isset` because it will always be set when the form is submitted. It will either be blank or with value.

Comment: what do you get in $headline variable ??

Comment: did you added if inside elseif.if answer if yes then why there is no else. And top if elseif doess not have any else

Comment: Using `if($variable)` and then using `isset` to check if the variable even exists only _after_ that makes no sense.

Comment: You should use `var_export` when exporting PHP value literals, otherwise one could inject arbitrary PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

your code is like this

```
<?php 
if($_POST['header']){
    if(isset($_POST['header']) && trim($_POST['header']) != "")
    {
        //some code
    }
}

:
:
:
:
elseif($_POST['vidid']) 
{
    if(isset($_POST['vidid']) && trim($_POST['vidid']) != "")
    {
        //some code
    }
}

?>
```

but if elseif must be like this

```
if{
}
elseif{
}
else{
}
```

but your code does not contain else you added if inside if or else if. you are checking header in post method first in upper If then using isset .if you are using isset you do not need to check for null separately isset will check for you.you can check empty string directly why using trim.

so your code shold be like this

```
<?php 
if((isset($_POST['header']) && $_POST['header']!= "")
    {
        //some code
    }

:
:
:
:
if(isset($_POST['vidid']) && $_POST['vidid'] != "")
    {
        //some code
    }

?>
```

if still not working that means parameter name in $_post are mismatch with actual or they are really null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
$options = array(
    "header" => "assets/config_header.php", 
    "color" => "assets/config_header5.php", 
    "headline" => "assets/config_header1.php", 
    "color1" => "assets/config_header6.php", 
    "subhead" => "assets/config_header2.php", 
    "color2" => "assets/config_header7.php", 
    "prodname" => "assets/config_header3.php", 
    "vivid" => "assets/config_header3.php"
);

foreach ($options as $key => $file) {
    if($_POST[$key]) {
        if(isset($_POST[$key]) && trim($_POST[$key]) != ""){
            $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
            fwrite($fp, '<?php');
            fwrite($fp, ' ');
            fwrite($fp, '$' . $key . ' = "'.trim($_POST[$key]).'";');
            fwrite($fp, ' ');
            fwrite($fp, '?>');
            fclose($fp);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better way - if you do not use closing php tag.